# Dynamics CRM Email correlation issue

Tags: dynamics-crm

When a user creates a case, an email is shot. If this email is answered, it can be tracked. Issue is that sometimes, the person who replies to the email clears the subject text field. Instead of getting `RE:` or `RV:`, once this subject is cleared the email is "lost" and cannot be tracked.

Does anyone know a solution? Some kind of "hidden code" inside the email that let us still track the email even the user changes the subject?

Comment: Sorry the title is wrong!!! Email CRM Dynamics issue should say!

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

CRM emails & replies are tracked as conversations, regarded to existing records using these correlation techniques, but somewhat they are tightly coupled with Email subject. So advise the users not to edit the subject line when they reply, maybe some info text in Email signature or something.

> [image]
>
> Correlation is used to link an email to records in CRM, three methods of automatic correlation exist;
> •   Email headers
> •   Smart Matching
> •   Tracking token

[Learn more](https://neilparkhurst.com/2016/11/19/mb2-710-track-and-correlate-email/)

Each of this has its own limitations and one will overcome the limits & solve the problem of others, but still Subject plays a crucial role - like tracking token per activity and regular expression based Smart matching.

Otherwise you have to write a plugin on Email pre-create, to manually correlate which is unnecessary overkill.